# how to prevent the move of cells in excel when using Worksheet_Change Event

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and it works just fine.
The only problem is that after i press enter ,in cell "A2" for example, instead of moving down to cell "A3", like it normally would - it moves to cell "E3", so it makes hard on the user to type.

Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A2:M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
Dim LASTROW As Long
TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim intx As Variant
For i = 2 To TheLastRow
    If Range("a" & i) = Range("a" & i + 1) Then
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.Color = Range("a" & i).Interior.Color
        intx = intx + 0
    Else
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 - intx
     intx = intx + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To TheLastRow
    Range("e" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",HYPERLINK(""PCDOCS://PCDOCS_JLM/""&RC[-1]&""/R"",""link""))"
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE in VBA, so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A2:M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
Dim LASTROW As Long
TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim intx As Variant
For i = 2 To TheLastRow
    If Range("a" & i) = Range("a" & i + 1) Then
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.Color = Range("a" & i).Interior.Color
        intx = intx + 0
    Else
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 - intx
     intx = intx + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To TheLastRow
    Range("e" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",HYPERLINK(""PCDOCS://PCDOCS_JLM/""&RC[-1]&""/R"",""link""))"
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to your code, and when I press `{enter}` on cell "A2" it performs the code and "jumps" to cell "A3".

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim C As Range
Dim intx As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A2:M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

' loop through all cells with data in column "A"
For Each C In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If C.Value = C.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        C.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 14).Interior.Color = C.Interior.Color
    Else
        C.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 14).Interior.Color = 46 - intx
        intx = intx + 1
    End If
Next C

' loop through all cells with data in column "E"
For Each C In Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    C.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",HYPERLINK(""PCDOCS://PCDOCS_JLM/""&RC[-1]&""/R"",""link""))"
Next C

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Read out the Address from the Cell that Trigert the Event and save them.
After your code is done, you can select the Cell, 1 Row below.
Hope this Helps.

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    Dim rngAddress As String
    rngAddress  = Target.Address

    Range("A2:M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Dim LASTROW As Long
    TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Dim intx As Variant
    For i = 2 To TheLastRow
        If Range("a" & i) = Range("a" & i + 1) Then
            Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.Color = Range("a" & i).Interior.Color
            intx = intx + 0
        Else
            Range("A" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 - intx
         intx = intx + 1
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 2 To TheLastRow
        Range("e" & i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",HYPERLINK(""PCDOCS://PCDOCS_JLM/""&RC[-1]&""/R"",""link""))"
    Next i

Range(rngAddress).offset(1,0).select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```